# Running Moodle on Bluemix: Error No Such File or Directory

Tags: apache, moodle, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, php-extension

I am trying to install and run Moodle on a PHP runtime in Bluemix, but after installation and running the application via mymoodle.mybluemix.net, the server returns the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/vcap/app/htdocs/lib/classes/component.php):     
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/install.php 
on line 95

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/vcap/app/htdocs/lib/classes/component.php' 
(include_path='../lib/php:/home/vcap/app/lib') in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/install.php on line 95
```

I created and cloned the PHP Runtime in Bluemix to my localhost, and copy-pasted the Moodle source code distribution in there. It runs fine on localhost.

Note: when I 'cf push' to Bluemix, I do see some errors in the deployment log, but it doesn't stop the package from being build and deployed, with the app running:

```
ERR The extension 'pcre' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'simplexml' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'tokenizer' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'dom' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'json' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'reflection' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'spl' is not provided by this buildpack.
[...]
ERR Loading composer repositories with package information
ERR Installing dependencies from lock file
ERR Nothing to install or update
ERR Generating autoload files
```

I posted this issue therefore in a separate thread here.
I don't immediately see a relation with the errors in this thread.

Any help is appreciated. I am hoping to be able to solve the dependencies with composer or CF's bp-config, and avoid having to build my own docker container or VM installation.

Comment: A critical missing piece of information here, is that the install.php contains a line (pointing to the missing files) with __DIR__/lib/classes/component.php. the files are there in the subfolder of the installation, but the __DIR__ must not be pointing to the correct installation folder/root folder.

Comment: I'd get those dependencies fixed first, then see if there is still a problem. Look at the php info on your local host and see if those dependencies are working locally.